# Central limit theorem for one-dependent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $I_A=1$ if the condition $A$ holds and $0$ otherwise.

Let $ X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be iid Bernoulli($p$) random variables, that is, $P(X_i=1)=p$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-p$.

Let $\displaystyle T_n=\sum_{i=1}^nI_{(X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1)}$.

Show that $\sqrt{n} \left(\frac{T_n}{n}-p^2\right)\overset{D}{\rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2)$ and determine $\sigma^2$.

I can show that $E(T_n)=p^2$ and $Var(T_n)=p^2+2p^3-3p^4$ but I have difficulty for proving limiting distribution.

Comment: The elements of the sum are not independent, so you cant use directly the CLT.

Comment: What do you know about the central limit theorem? You probably already saw the CLT for independent random variables. Maybe also for martingales? Or for array of independent random variables? In this case, cut the index set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ into blocks $\{\ell_k+1,\dots,\ell_{k+1}\}$. These blocks are disjoint but the random variables $\sum_{i=\ell_k+1}^{\ell_{k+1}}I_{(X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1)}$ are not independent. However, $\sum_{i=\ell_k+2}^{\ell_{k+1}-1}I_{(X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1)}$ are independent and the global behavior of the partial sums is the same.

Comment: Thanks, Davide. I do not want to use more advanced tools such as martingales but only elementary tools. Your "blocking" argument is not very clear for me.

Comment: The idea is to ignore a few elements of the sum so that the remaining "chunks" are independent.

Comment: I can split the $T_n$ into two parts, one $\displaystyle E_n=\sum_{i, even}^nI_{(X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1)}$ and $\displaystyle O_n=\sum_{i, odd}^nI_{(X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1)}$.  So now each part is the sum of i.i.d. random variables so after subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation they would converge to standard normal. I know $E_n$ and $O_n$ are correlated. Which theorem can I use to conclude that after normalization the original sum would converge  in distribution to standard normal?