# a confusion about independence related to random variables

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be independent and identically distributed continuous random variables. Then we know that for any $s,t$ real numbers $$P(X_1\leq s, X_2\leq t)=P(X_1\leq s)P(X_2\leq t)$$.

Then, can I claim that

1. $P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)=P(X_1\leq X_3)P(X_2\leq X_3)$?

If this is true, then I can also claim that
$$P(\max(X_1,X_2)<\min(X_3,X_4))=P(X_1<\min(X_3,X_4))P(X_2<\min(X_3,X_4))$$
and then iterating this I can get
$$P(\max(X_1,X_2)<\min(X_3,X_4))=P(X_1<X_3)^4$$.

This is not correct because my simulation result contradicts. What is wrong here?

Comment: "Then, can I claim that $P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)=P(X_1\leq X_3)P(X_2\leq X_3)$?" -- No.

Comment: Could you please explain why? this is very tricky.

Comment: In the context you've given, you can evaluate $$P(X_1 \leq X_3, X_2 \leq X_3) = 1/3 \\ P(X_1 \leq X_3) = 1/2 \\ P(X_2 \leq X_3) = 1/2$$ so $1/3 \neq 1/4$.

Comment: The intuition is that the event $X_1\le X_3$ tells you something about $X_3$, so it tells you something about the event $X_2\le X_3$ even though it tells you nothing about $X_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim
$$
P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)=P(X_1\leq X_3)P(X_2\leq X_3)
$$
is not true because the events $\{X_1\leq X_3\}$ and $\{X_2\leq X_3\}$ are not independent. The following should be true:
$$
P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)=\int_{\mathbb R}P(X_1\leq x)P(X_2\leq x)\,p(x)\,dx
$$
where $p(x)$ is the PDF of the $X_i\,.$

Since $X_i$ are i.i.d. we can write this integral using the cumulative distribution function $F$ of $X_i$ as
$$
\int_\mathbb R F^2(x)\,p(x)\,dx=\int_\mathbb R F^2(x)\,F'(x)\,dx.
$$
Integration by parts now gives
$$
-\underbrace{\int_\mathbb R 2F(x)\,F'(x)\,F(x)\,dx}_{2\,P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)}+\underbrace{F^3(x)\Big|_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}}_{1}
$$
It follows -as ***Brian Moehring*** and ***Milten*** have pointed out- that
$$
\boxed{\quad P(X_1\leq X_3, X_2\leq X_3)=\int_\mathbb R F^2(x)\,F'(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\,.\quad}
$$

Comment: I think these types of questions are helpful for students, this is why I asked this question.

Comment: what a wonderful community we have :)

Comment: I would like to take your attention to the following question as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642494/377953

Comment: And as Brian Moehring pointed out, the integral will always evaluate to $1/3$ because of the symmetry. (The event is “$X_3$ is the largest”)

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing that again and also thanks to @Brian Moehring ! Every time I am on MSE I learn something new.

Comment: +1 with a technical caveat: if the distribution has a nonzero singular part, then there's no PDF and then your steps don't work as written.  However, each statement you wrote has an sister statement using Riemann-Stieltjes integrals that works in full generality and gives the same conclusion.

Comment: Learning doesn't stop. Thanks !